# How do I add the year to the menu bar in OSX High Sierra?

Tags: macos, date-time

So, Tue 19 Jun 2018 13:04:41 ( instead of Tue 19 Jun 13:04:41 ). I want to do this because I take Screen Shots and want to use the Menu Bar Date Time as a reference. So if a series of screen shots spans a number of years it's not very helpful if the year is missing when trying to compile a time line of data.

Comment: https://github.com/matryer/bitbar

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this with Apple's menu bar clock in High Sierra.

But [Day-O 2](https://shauninman.com/archive/2016/10/20/day_o_2_mac_menu_bar_clock) is a free menu bar clock that is highly configurable and can do what you want. To get the date/time format you mentioned, click on Day-O 2 in the menu bar, select `Preferences` and change the `Date & Time Format` to:-

```
E dd MMM Y hh:mm:ss
```

(The date & format patterns are described [here](https://shauninman.com/day-o/datetime.html).)

The above format results in the following menu clock:-

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks very much. More power to you.